# Console program, static methods, socket becomes null

Tags: c#, .net, static, static-methods, static-members

```
class Program
{
    static Socket m_sock;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Socket m_sock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        .
        .
        .
        m_sock.Connect(ipendLocalhost);
        SendRequest("command");
    }

    static void SendRequest(string sCommand)
    {
       .
       .
     **m_sock.Send(szCommand, iBytesToSend, SocketFlags.None);**
     }
```

---

When it comes to Send method I get NullReferenceException. In debug (I added m_sock to watch) I See that when program enters SendRequest method m_sock becomes null. I can't understand why is it happening and where the problem is. Please help.

Comment: In your main, change `Socket m_sock=` to `m_sock=`. You don't want to declare a local variable with the same name, you simply need to initialize the global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m_sock` is defined internal to Main as well as at class level, You don't have to define it again in the Main, just initialize it, like:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        m_sock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

notice the `Socket` is removed.

Currently your Main method is initializing a local `m_sock`, and that is why your class level `m_sock` is staying null, later when you access it in the static method you are getting the exception.

Answer (score 2):

Because you declare another `m_sock` in Main

```
Socket m_sock=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

change it to

```
m_sock=new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

Comment: that is the cause, but what is the solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from your declaration in Main, `Socket m_sock=` hides the field at class level.

```
static Socket m_sock;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket m_sock = new Socket // Create a new Socket in m_sock from the Main method only
    SendRequest("command");
}

static void SendRequest(string sCommand)
{
  m_sock.Send() // Uses the socket at the Class level, which is not initialized
}
```

Change the initialization to

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    m_sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    m_sock.Connect(ipendLocalhost);

    SendRequest("command");
}
```

or remove the class level declaration and pass it as a variable

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Socket m_sock= new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    m_sock.Connect(ipendLocalhost);

    SendRequest(m_sock, "command");
}

static void SendRequest(Socket m_sock, string sCommand)
{
   m_sock.Send(szCommand, iBytesToSend, SocketFlags.None);
}
```

Comment: +1 for suggestion to pass it around. `static` variables should be used carefully, and in this case should also be disposed of.